# Laravel MongoDB - command delete requires authentication

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

Developing a Laravel app using Mongodb as database, I came accross a weird issue today.

Somehow, when I use the app, anywhere I need to use a mongo command I get a "command  requires authentication". Which obviously means I am not connected to the db but "php artisan migrate --database=mongodb" does work with no problem, all indexes etc are created.

Using the same credentials as in my .env I can connect to the DB using Compass.

**Is there any reason the app would use a different config than the migrate command?**

For reference:

###### config/database.php

```
'mongodb' => [
            'driver' => 'mongodb',
            'host' => env('MONGO_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'dsn' => env('MONGO_DB_DSN', 'mongodb://') . env('MONGO_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => 27017,
            'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE', 'rte_golf'),
            'username' => env('MONGO_DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MONGO_DB_PASSWORD'),
            'options' => [
                // here you can pass more settings to the Mongo Driver Manager
                // see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.construct.php under "Uri Options" for a list of complete parameters that you can use
                'database' => env('DB_AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE', 'admin'), // required with Mongo 3+
            ],
        ],
```

###### .env

```
MONGO_DB_HOST=mongodb
MONGO_DB_DATABASE=rte_golf
MONGO_DB_USERNAME=username
MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=password
```

###### docker-compose creating the mongo image

```
mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: username
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - backoffice
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the following line to your docker-compose to enable auth mode

```
 command: [--auth]
```

for example

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   mongo:
      container_name: mongodb
      image: mongo
      ports:
       - "27017:27017"
      volumes:
       - mongodbdata:/data/db
      command: [--auth]
      restart: always
volumes:
   mongodbdata:

networks:
   default:
      external:
         name: mongo-network
```

Comment: The auth mode is already enabled though this:
environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: username
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password